# General method for unpacking and combining nested tuples

Tags: python

I've generated the cartesian product of three dicts thus:

```
import itertools
combined = list(itertools.product(foo, bar, baz))
```

So my list now looks like:

```
[(('text a', 'value a'), ('text b', 'value b'), ('text c', 'value c')), … ]
```

What I want to do is unpack this list such that I end up with a list of lists containing the flattened nested tuples' text and values:

```
[['text a text b text c', 'value a value b value c'], … ]
```

Is there an efficient general method for doing this?

Follow-up (having seen Dan D.'s answer):

What if my tuples looked like

```
(('text a', float a), ('text b', float b), ('text c', float c ))
```

and I wanted to add the floats instead of concatenating the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to cram everything on one line:

```
def combine(items):
    for tuples in items:
        text, numbers = zip(*tuples)
        yield ' '.join(text), sum(numbers)

print list(combine(product( ... )))
```

Comment: Agreed. Dan's answer is more concise for the specific case, but this is more flexible and more easily adaptable.

Answer (score 4):

```
map(lambda v: map(' '.join, zip(*v)), combined)
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalization:

```
def combine(functions, data):
    for elements in data:
        yield [f(e) for f, e in zip(functions, zip(*elements))]

# A simple function for demonstration.
def pipe_join(args):
    return '|'.join(args)

some_data = [
    (('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', 30)),
    (('D', 40), ('E', 50), ('F', 60)),
    (('G', 70), ('H', 80), ('I', 90)),
]

for c in combine( [pipe_join, sum], some_data ):
    print c
```

Comment: This is amazing and terrifyingly complex (the yield statement in combine(), that is), all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> What if my tuples looked like
>
> combined = (('text a', float a), ('text b', float b), ('text c', float c ))
>
> and I wanted to add the floats instead of concatenating the values?

Try using the built-in sum() function:

```
sum(x for (_,x) in combined)
```